# Spring Boot JPA working in 2.0.6.RELEASE but 2.1.1.RELEASE is not working for same pom.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Spring Boot JPA working in 2.0.6.RELEASE but 2.1.1.RELEASE is not working for same pom.xml

When i try to use spring boot 2.0.6-Release POM version then boot rest sevice is working, if i try to upgrade the POM version to 2.1.1 then its throwing below Class Def Found Exception.

Spring Boot 2.1.1 Release Exception below,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory
at org.springframework.data.jpa.util.BeanDefinitionUtils.<clinit>(BeanDefinitionUtils.java:54) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.EntityManagerBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(EntityManagerBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.java:71) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at com.restservice.SpringBootAppApplication.main(SpringBootAppApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
... 13 common frames omitted
```

Please find my POM.XML below,

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
            <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: The upgrade requires a new version of the JPA API. I would guess that Maven has corrupted its jar file when it downloaded it. Try clearing out Maven's cache and building your application again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you build the project after changing the project?

Just clear maven `.m2` local repository and try to build it again using

```
mvn clean install
```

should resolve the issue.

location of m2 repository : `C:\users\[your user name]\.m2\repository` (windows)

for linux : It is located in the `/home/.m2` directory, the folder is probably hidden. So, you'll need to press `Ctrl+H` to see hidden folders.